# chrome puts ==$0 after my code in head of my website ! what is this?

Tags: html, web, header

automatically google chrome puts something after my codes
shat are the meaning of them or works?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qrv1B.png)

Comment: @ConstantinGroß While the question is rather simple, it is not off-topic — see [help/on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "if your question generally covers… software tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development
…then you’re in the right place to ask your question!". Chrome Developer Tools certainly falls under "software tools commonly used by programmers".

Comment: @Amadan thanks for the clarification. I wan't too sure if it's too generic, so I didn't vote for a close anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on an element in the Element pane, Chrome assigns the element to a variable, so that you can inspect it in the Console pane. `$0` informs you of the name of the variable it got assigned to. Switch to Console and try:

```
> $0
<   <meta ....>
> $0.name
< "robots"
...
```